# how `commitNow()` and `postDelayed` make this code works?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have tried to do some fragment work. I put a recyclerview layout into the layout, and init the recyclerview in `onCreateView` of my fragment. 
Finally, I set the recyclerview's pos dynamic with its items.

I have the code like this make it works correctly with `commitNow` and `postDelayed` even with 0 mills delay, but I do not know why:

```
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.parentLayout, popupFragment)
                .commitNow();
        new Handler().postDelayed(()->popupFragment.show(), 0);
```

But i tried:

```
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.parentLayout, popupFragment)
                .commitNow();
        popupFragment.show();
```

```
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.parentLayout, popupFragment)
                .commitNowAllowingStateLoss();
        popupFragment.show();
```

```
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.parentLayout, popupFragment)
                .runOnCommit(()->popupFragment.show())
                .commitNowAllowingStateLoss();
```

```
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.parentLayout, popupFragment)
                .runOnCommit(()->popupFragment.show())
                .commitNow();
```

They all get an uninitialized height.

From my guess, this is about `postDelayed` makes the code runs on next loop, however, `runOnCommit` seems also make the commit first and then run the runnable, why this is not working?

Comment: it also failed with 
`
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.parentLayout, popupFragment)
                .commit();
        new Handler().postDelayed(()->popupFragment.show(), 0);
`

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion if you want a "popup" fragment would be to utilize the AlertDialog class like so (and refactor your code out of onCreateView as you are not guaranteed to have a reference to an activity from onCreateView):

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle onSaveInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, onSaveInstanceState);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
    View popupFragmentsResourceView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_popup_view, null);
    builder.setView(popupFragmentsResourceView);
    //grab controls here
    //RecyclerView rv = popupFragmentsResourceView.findViewById(R.id.some_id);
    //rv.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(getActivity));
    //set a click button for your dialog builder
    builder.show();
}
```